# Class accessor return nil

Tags: ruby

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :var
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  var = "bar"
  p var   # print "bar"
end

p Bar.var # print nil
```

Why Bar.var not return "bar"?

how can i add getter/setter for class variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Bar < Foo
  var = "bar" # this is assignment to local variable, not the accessor
end
```

Use `self` to tell ruby that you want to call the method, not create local variable.

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :var
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  self.var = "bar"
  var # => "bar"
end

Bar.var # => "bar"
```

Comment: Sergio, it's perhaps worth noting that `@var = "bar"` could also be used.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is worth noting. Thanks for noting it :)